# Elastic Search "should" clause not working as expected when "should", "must" and "must_not" clause are present

Tags: elasticsearch

I've loaded the data provided [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/elasticsearch/master/docs/src/test/resources/accounts.json) into elastic search.

Now I'm trying to query for Accounts.

1. Age Must be 38.
2. State Should not be "ID".
3. **Address Should Contain Either**: (This is not Working)

   - The text "lane" OR
   - The a complete text "mill avenue"

**Request** : POST - http://localhost:9200/bank/account/_search?pretty

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "address": "lane" } },
        { "match_phrase": { "address": "mill avenue" } }
      ],
      "must": [
        { "match": { "age": "38" } }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        { "match": { "state": "ID" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "_source": ["account_number", "balance", "firstname", "lastname", "age", "email", "address", "state"],
  "sort": [
    { "account_number": "asc" },
    { "balance": "desc"}
  ]
}
```

**Response** :

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 36,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "bank",
        "_type": "account",
        "_id": "21",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "account_number": 21,
          "firstname": "Estella",
          "address": "859 Portal Street",
          "balance": 7004,
          "state": "WV",
          "age": 38,
          "email": "estellapaul@zillatide.com",
          "lastname": "Paul"
        },
        "sort": [
          21,
          7004
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can check the response. The record with address **"859 Portal Street"** was received and **it doesn't contain "lane" or "mill avenue"**.

Elastic Search Version : 5.1.1

**----Edit----**
Solution (Thanks to @Lax and @mattweber as posted [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-search-should-clause-not-working-as-expected-when-should-must-and-must-not-clause-are-present/70231/2?u=bandikishores)): 
`minimum_should_match` is needed if must/must_not is present.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        { "match": { "address": "avenue" } },
        { "match_phrase": { "address": "Williams Place" } }
      ],
      "must": [
        { "match": { "age": "38" } }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        { "match": { "state": "ID" } }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "balance": {
            "gte": 20000,
            "lte": 30000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "_source": ["account_number", "balance", "firstname", "lastname", "age", "email", "address", "state"],
  "sort": [
    { "account_number": "asc" },
    { "balance": "desc"}
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_balance": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "balance"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you indexing the docs? What tokenizers or Analyzers are you using while indexing and quering?

Comment: Try to add minimum_should_match" : 1 after the should array

Comment: @Lax Yes, minimum_should_match is needed when must/must_not is present. It worked after adding it. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept and close this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When must/must_not present you need to add :

```
minimum_should_match" : 1
```

after the should array

Comment: When you have no should array, but just `must` and `must_not`, it looks like `"minimum_should_match" : 0` does the trick? Is such magic documented somewhere?

Comment: "minimum_should_match" works only for "should" clause
[reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) 
"You can use the minimum_should_match parameter to specify the number or percentage of should clauses returned documents must match"